# Convert recessed NEMA 14-50 to direct-wire Tesla wall connector

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m looking to convert my recessed NEMA 14-50 outlet into a direct-wired Tesla wall connector.

Is there any way to somehow mount the wall connector over the junction box to keep it recessed and the wire hidden? Or do I have to extend the box outward to use conduit?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Wall Connector installation instructions, you can drill a knockout in the back bottom left or right. You’ll need a step bit to drill the appropriate sized hole.

Answer (score 3):

### Use a knockout faceplate and a flex (air conditioner) whip

If you don't want to have a box sticking out of the wall, and don't want to have to deal with burying a box behind the Tesla EVSE itself, you can still do this.  For this solution, you'll need a faceplate for your box with a ½" KO on it, a KO punch set to enlarge that KO to ¾" since they don't make faceplates with larger knockouts, and an 8/2 air conditioner whip kit.

Once the faceplate's knockout is enlarged to the correct size, you can then fit the right-angle fitting on the whip to it and the straight fitting on the whip into one side of the EVSE.  From there, it's simple: just connect the black wires to the hots and the green wire to the grounding connection on each end.

Comment: 8/2 is too small. Tesla recommends minimum 6 AWG copper. 4 is ideal. The EVSE can pull 48A on a 60A breaker and you can’t do that on an 8 gauge wire.

Comment: @RibaldEddie -- I'm assuming from the 50A receptacle that the OP has a 50A circuit and thus will be commissionng the unit at 40A

Answer (score 2):

That is a fitment question.  The answer is, "It's allowed if the Tesla Wall Connector is designed to do that" - in which case the instructions will say, or it will be obvious due to the provided knockouts. NEC 110.3.

However, the "sure thing" is to a) use an ["Extension junction box"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-x-1-1-2-in-D-Square-Drawn-Extension-Ring-with-1-2-in-and-3-4-in-KO-s-for-Switch-Boxes-187/202097248?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-202245821-_-202097248-_-N) mounted on top of the existing box. That gives it side ports.  Then b) have a short run of conduit such as EMT to the Tesla Wall Connector itself.

At that point two black copper #8 THHN wires can be run for the two hot wires.  THHN is good for 50A if it is the only circuit in the pipe.  NEC 310.15(B)(16) and 110.14, allowing 75C thermal rating if the item is marked for it.   If you think #8 is 40A, that only applies to NM-B and UF type cables, per 334.80.

EMT metal conduit takes care of ground for you, or you can run a #10 copper ground, either bare or green insulation.

With EMT, you use [connectors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-Electrical-Metallic-Tube-EMT-Compression-Connectors-5-Pack-26230/100559992) to enter the round "knockout holes" on junction box and Wall Connector.

The tubing cuts easily with a hack saw, which makes the least burrs on the inside, easily handled by a few twists of the wrist with your [multi-function pliers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-8-in-6-in-1-Multi-Function-Pliers-99999/312980360) (it is wedge shaped).
It doesn't need to be perfectly square. Don't use a tubing cutter, too hard to de-burr.

I use this [little hack saw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Capri-Tools-12-in-Hack-Saw-with-Soft-Handle-20105/304795754) because it keeps my toolbox small.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Alternatively can I remove the electric box, repair the drywall, mount the wall connector over the new drywall? then have the cable exiting the drywall directly into the wall connector with a plastic clamp? There’s no other junctions or use for the box at the moment other than the outlet.

Comment: @user150801 your alternate answer is "maybe". Please feel free to ask that as a whole new question and _include pictures_ of the situation to ensure everyone who isn't there in your garage understands what's involved.

Comment: @user150801  It would surprise me if the Wall Connector was designed for a boxless back entry.   Sure if the instructions say that is allowed - but if it does, it will also allow mounting **over** the box.  So, might as well just do that.  Otherwise, you're playing with fire: Suppose you discover you don't have the cable length needed to get the jacket into the clamp *properly*.  What would you realistically do then? Haha I think we both know that bit of code/safety would be sacrificed on the altar of "git-r-dun".

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for installing the wall connection says, you can drill a hole in the back, at the bottom left or right. This requires a step drill.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Your answer could use some clarity. Is this hole for a mounting screw or something else? Please provide the source for your information.